# |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field while passing context from my django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

Help!!! I'm lost on this error:  while trying to submit this form and pass it content as a context:

I see that the indentation of my view is correct as well as the definitions of my form
**View**

```
def costm_questions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = labor_questions(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           cost_dict= dict()
           cost_dict['Union_PWR']= form.cleaned_data['Union_PWR']
           cost_dict['UnionLabor_area']= form.cleaned_data['UnionLabor_area']
           cost_dict['After_Hours_Req']= form.cleaned_data['After_Hours_Req']
           cost_dict['infectious_control_Req']=form.cleaned_data['infectious_control_Req']
           cost_dict['No_Core_Drills']= form.cleaned_data['No_Core_Drills']
           cost_dict['Armored_fiber_req']= form.cleaned_data['Armored_fiber_req']
           cost_dict['cost_dict']= cost_dict
           context = {
              'cost_dict': cost_dict,
           } 
           return render(request, 'building_form.html', context)
    else:
        form = labor_questions()`enter code here`
   return render(request, 'cost_questions_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**Forms**

```
class labor_questions(forms.Form):
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
    LABOR_AREA_CHOICES= ((1, '1) Chicago'), (2 ,'2) Manhattan'), (3 ,'3) NYC Metro'), (4 ,'4) Los 
    Angeles'),
                    (4 ,'5) San Francisco'), (5 ,'6) Philadelphia'), (5 ,'6) Other'))
    AFTER_HOURS_CHOICES= ((1, '1) No'), (2, '2) Yes, Mon-Fri'), (3,'3) Yes, weekends only'))
    Union_PWR = forms.ChoiceField(choices = BOOL_CHOICES, label="Is Union Labor or Prevailing Wage Required?",
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True) #Is Union Labor or Prevailing Wage Required?
    UnionLabor_area= forms.ChoiceField(choices = LABOR_AREA_CHOICES, label="if yes please choose union area",
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
    After_Hours_Req= forms.ChoiceField(choices = AFTER_HOURS_CHOICES, label="Is after-hours work required?",
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
    infectious_control_Req= forms.ChoiceField(choices = BOOL_CHOICES, label="Is tenting required for infectious control?",
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
    No_Core_Drills = forms.IntegerField(label='How many core drills will be required?', required=True)
    Armored_fiber_req= forms.ChoiceField(choices = BOOL_CHOICES, label="Is armored fiber cabling required?",
                              initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

My html code is calling for crispy but I see the format are correct

**html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Cost Questions form{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action = {% url 'cost_info' %}>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <div class="card w-100">
                        <div class="card-header"><h6>Project Cost Questions</h6></div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">{{ form.Union_PWR|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                                    <div class="col">{{ form.UnionLabor_area|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">{{form.After_Hours_Req|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">{{form.infectious_control_Req|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">{{form.No_Core_Drills|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">{{form.Armored_fiber_req|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="CostInfo" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
            <br/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**trace back**
[image]

Comment: Can you share also **building_form.html**?

Answer (score 0):

first check your model's fields
then your view, that you bring essential fields into 'fields tags'
class ArticleCreate(CreateView):
model = Article
fields = ['title', 'slug', .....]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.